# Php reading files from directory

Tags: php, directory

I have this code which reads files from directory:

```
//directory to read
$dir = ($_REQUEST['dir']);

if(file_exists($dir)==false){
    echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' not found!';
}else if( !is_readable($dir) ) {
    echo 'Directory \'', $dir, '\' is not readable! Check your permissions.';
}else{

    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
        $file_type = explode(".", $filename);
        $extension = strtolower(array_pop($file_type));
        if(in_array($extension, $allowed_files) == true){
            $mediaArr[] = $filename;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($mediaArr);
}
```

If I enter path as this: 
    http://www.mydomain.com/some_folder/

I get an error "Directory http://www.mydomain.com/some_folder/ not found"

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP file system functions work with file system paths. There are different [protocol wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) you can use with the file system functions, but I don't see how they would be of any help here.

Just use the file system paths.